# how to handle onTouchMove event in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, touch

I want to fire a event on a react element where i currently move my finger across. I tried `onTouchMove` but it fires only for the first element i touch and then keeps firing it. The only way i'm able to track the currently touched element down is the `elementFromPoint()` method.

```
handleTouchMove(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let changedTouch = event.changedTouches[0];
    let elem = document.elementFromPoint(changedTouch.clientX, changedTouch.clientY);
}
```

Now i have the element, but i'm working with the dom directly. Any ideas how to avoid this?